# ASP.NET Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, web-config

Here is my .config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn" path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

When I do that on IIS7 it's ok, but on IIS6...

Under IIS7:

- Browse /Home/
- Redirect to /LogOn (because anonymous)
- Display /LogOn page

It's OK,

But under IIS6

- Browse /Home/
- Redirect to /LogOn (because anonymous)
- Can't display /LogOn page because anonymous :(

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are denying anonymous users acces to your login page. Add to your web.config

```
<location path="login.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

substitute login.aspx with your login page.